# Big O of binary search tree check program

Tags: python, big-o

I was wondering what is the big O notation for the runtime of my program to check if a binary tree is a binary search tree? I think it is `O(n)` because the recursion in my algorithm goes to each node but a part of my thinks it is not. I was wondering if someone could help me confirm this

```
def isBST(root, max_val=sys.maxsize, min_val=-sys.maxsize):
    if root is None:
        return True
    else:
        if root.left:
            if root.left.value >= max_val:
                return False
        if root.right:
            if root.right.value < min_val:
                return False
        return isBST(root.left, root.value, min_val) and isBST(root.right, max_val, root.value)
```

Comment: Yes, it’s O(n). The only non-constant-time step (assuming comparisons are, which seems pretty reasonable) is the last line and it only goes downwards one level, so as long as you really have a tree, that’s the complexity.

Comment: @RyanO'Hara thanks for the confirmation! =D

Comment: You can see it is O(N) because it is called once for each node in the tree.